# Any ASP.NET MVC sample using DI, AOP, POCO, UoW, Mocks, and Unit Tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Can somebody point me to a ASP.NET MVC 2 sample with following features (most of them):

- Dependency Inversion using any DI framework
- Repository pattern & Unit of Work pattern
- Entity Framework 4.1 and POCO (or NHibernate)
- Unit Testing using any framework
- Mocking using any mocking framework
- Data Annotations, Validations
- ViewModel and AutoMapper
- AJAX
- jQuery for Client side validations & UI
- With some cross-cutting concerns like logging addressed using AOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally complete, but I do have an app that includes several of those things:

https://bitbucket.org/dswersky/mvcconferencescheduler

Comment: Is it a public repository? I don't seems to have access to it.

Comment: Just made it public, should be able to clone it now.